# PowerShell: Loading a array into a WPF ListBox

Tags: wpf, powershell, listbox

Starting with this bit of code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6340784/704977):

```
stringList.ForEach(item => listBox1.Items.Add(item));
```

I've put my own variables into the line like so:

```
$listAgencies = $Window.FindName('listAgencies')
$arr_listAgencies = ($hash_AgencyOffices['ADMIN1','ADMIN2'].Keys | ForEach-Object ToString)
$arr_listAgencies.ForEach(item => $listAgencies.Items.Add(item))
```

I have confirmed that `$arr_listAgencies` is a list of the values I need in the ListBox `$listAgencies`, but I'm guessing I am entirely missing the importance of `item` in that last line: `(item => $listAgencies.Items.Add(item))`.

When I run this PS kindly informs me that there is a *missing ')' in method call* and there is an *unexpected token 'item' in expression or statement*.

Is `item` supposed to be `$._`, the pipeline variable? I thought that might have been it and tried it, but the error was essentially the same.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `item => {code}` the `=>` operator is not available in PowerShell. It's a lambda expression operator for C#.

In order to achieve what you want, try this

```
$arr_listAgencies | ForEach-Object {
    $listAgencies.Items.Add($_) | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: That indeed worked. Thank you for clarifying that for me.